# React Native: setState() does not re-render FlatList child component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In short, I have been following a tutorial found [here](https://shellmonger.com/2017/08/07/implementing-swipe-right-on-a-react-native-flatlist/).

It makes sense and it works, however, I have trouble understanding why the `FlatList` component needs to be assigned a `prop` to which a state is associated in order to re-render it when the state changes. If I omit the `extraData` prop as per the example, the `FlatList` doesn't get re-rendered. I thought `setState()` was supposed to re-render a component and all its children, but it doesn't in this instance: am I missing something here?

Thank you.

Comment: In his code, does he ever use the `extraData` prop? I can't seem to find it being used..

Comment: If you search the page for "Next, ensure that the FlatList is re-rendered when the state is changed. This is handled in the FlatList props" you will find it.

Answer (score 2):

if you take a look at this page https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html

you can see they are setting the `state.selected`, but i can't see that you/him are doing that in that tutorial, maybe its the this.state.selected that isnt set as a property?

i think you'll need to add the `selected` to state in your `onSelectItem()` method as this:

```
onSelectItem: (item) => {
    console.log('onSelectItem ', item);
    this.setState({
        selected: item
    });
},
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I have had a closer look at the documentation, and it seems like this is a peculiarity to FlatList:

"By passing extraData={this.state} to FlatList we make sure FlatList itself will re-render when the state.selected changes. Without setting this prop, FlatList would not know it needs to re-render any items because it is also a PureComponent and the prop comparison will not show any changes". So I am assuming this wouldn't happen with other components...

Comment: Apparently the difference here is that `FlatList` is a [`PureComponent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) : "React.PureComponent is exactly like React.Component, but implements shouldComponentUpdate() with a shallow prop and state comparison."

Answer (score 1):

After reading more attentively the [documentation for the `FlatList`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html) component (thanks, [@Lucas Reppe Welander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1273996/lucas-reppe-welander)), it has emerged that a FlatList is not a regular component, but it's actually a [`PureComponent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent). That means that even if the parent component's state changes, the `FlatList`'s "prop comparison will not show any changes", because `PureComponent` "implements `shouldComponentUpdate()` with a shallow prop and state comparison". I'm not entirely sure about all the intricacies this entails, but it's enough for me to understand why I need to use the `extraData` prop in this instance.